# Descriptive statistics, percentiles

Tags: excel, statistics, data-analysis

I am stuck in a statistics assignment, and would really appreciate some qualified help.

We have been given a data set and are then asked to find the 10% with the lowest rate of profit, in order to decide what Profit rate is the maximum in order to be considered for a program.

the data has: 
Mean = 3,61 
St. dev. = 8,38

I am thinking that i need to find the 10th percentile, and if i run the percentile function in excel it returns -4,71.

However I tried to run the numbers by hand using the z-score.

where z = -1,28

```
z=(x-μ)/σ
```

Solving for x

```
x= μ + z σ

x=3,61+(-1,28*8,38)=-7,116
```

My question is which of the two methods is the right one? if any at all.

I am thoroughly confused at this point, hope someone has the time to help.

Thank you

This is the assignment btw:

> "The Danish government introduces a program for economic growth and will
>   help the 10 percent of the rms with the lowest rate of prot. What rate
>   of prot is the maximum in order to be considered for the program given
>   the mean and standard deviation found above and assuming that the data
>   is normally distributed?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excel formula is giving the actual, empirical 10th percentile value *of your sample*

If the data you have includes all possible instances of whatever you’re trying to measure, then go ahead and use that.

If you’re sampling from a population and your sample size is small, use a t distribution or increase your sample size. If your sample size is healthy and your data are normally distributed, use z scores.

Short story is the different outcomes suggest the data you’ve supplied are not normally distributed.